# Waiting for threads to finish using join. Pretty basic

Tags: python, multithreading, join

I have a pretty basic assignment, but am having an issue making my main thread wait for all the other threads I spawn to complete.

This code does not do much of anything, it is just meant as a threading exercise.

Here is my code:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

def printNumbers(lowEnd, highEnd):
    while(lowEnd <= highEnd):
        print(repr(lowEnd))
        lowEnd += 1


countTo = 100000

#Test using 1 thread.        
startSingleThread = time.clock()
printNumbers(0,countTo)
elapsedSingleThread = (time.clock() - startSingleThread)

#Test using 10 threads
numberOfThreads      = 10
countAmountPerThread = countTo/numberOfThreads

startTenThread = time.clock()
for i in range(numberOfThreads):
    threadLowEnd  = i*countAmountPerThread
    threadHighEnd = (i+1)*countAmountPerThread
    t = Thread(target=printNumbers, args=(threadLowEnd,threadHighEnd,))
    t.start()

#Join all existing threads to main thread.
for thread in threading.enumerate():
    if thread is not threading.currentThread():
        thread.join()

elapsedTenThread = (time.clock() - startTenThread)

print("Time for 1 thread: " + repr(elapsedSingleThread))
print("time for 10 threads: " + repr(elapsedTenThread))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can’t see the stderr because you’re printing so much to stdout, but you have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 29, in <module>
    for thread in threading.enumerate():
NameError: name 'threading' is not defined
```

If I add `import threading` to the top, I get this output:

```
Time for 1 thread: 1.0224820000000001
time for 10 threads: 1.421281
```

…which might be what you were expecting to see, since it happens after all of the numbers are printed.

Comment: ....HAHA and now I hang my head in shame in the corner. Thanks buddy. Have a good one!

Comment: If you save the output to a file (e.g. `python3 test.py > out.txt`, or pipe it to `less`), then you will see the exception on your terminal.

Comment: Thanks! I will keep that in mind. Btw, you must have a pretty awesome machine. I thought mine was fast, but yours blew through this.

Comment: Hm. I'm using a 3.3 GHz i5. Wonder why it is so much slower for me. I am getting ~4 seconds for each.

Comment: @PFranchise: The task is IO bound. You might be on Windows, it has slow console output. If you redirect the output to a file (`python your_script.py > out.txt`) it should be much faster ([it is 0.05 seconds for 1 thread, and 0.02 seconds for 10 processes](http://ideone.com/nQk4H))

Comment: I tried this code on my computer, but I am unable to return to my main thread. I am running this code in linux on a core i7 processor. The version of python is 2.7. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

I have battled with this for a while, and I found a way that works for me - it is a collection of things that I found online, and now it is my main "pattern" when I work with multithreading applications. It is not specifically answering your question, but it shows a way to leverage the standard libraries in a Pythonic manner. However, keep in mind that NOTHING BEATS READING THE STANDARD LIBRARY DOCUMENTATION.

```
from threading import Thread, Lock
from Queue import Queue
from datetime import datetime
import time
import random

class Worker(Thread):
    """This is the main worker - it will process jobs as long as the "job
    queue" has jobs available.

    """
    # this lock is used to avoid messing up the screen output - only
    # one worker will write to screen at a given time. It is
    # technically a Mutual Exclusion (mutex)
    screen_mutex = Lock()

    def __init__(self, queue):
        # initialize the base class
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.queue = queue

    def log(self, message):
        """This convenience function is used to print a message to the
        screen. You are better off using the logging module, but
        beware! It is not thread safe (use a server).

        """
        Worker.screen_mutex.acquire()        
        print("{timestamp:%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f UTC} "
              "{name}: {message}".format(timestamp=datetime.utcnow(),
                                         name=self.getName(),
                                         message=message))
        Worker.screen_mutex.release()

    def run(self):
        """This is the method called when you start the thread."""
        # The following is an infinite loop which will continue
        # processing jobs as long as there are jobs available in the
        # queue
        while True:
            # this is how you get a job from the queue - this call
            # will block until a job is available, or when the parent
            # thread finishes
            job = self.queue.get()

            # in this case the job is simply a random number
            # indicating how many seconds to sleep (typical example)
            self.log("sleeping for {0} seconds".format(job))            
            time.sleep(job)            
            self.log("finished sleeping")
            # when the job is done, you signal the queue - refer to
            # the Queue module documentation
            self.queue.task_done()


def main(number_of_jobs=10, number_of_workers=3):
    # create the queue where you will put the jobs
    queue = Queue()

    # create the pool of workers (notice that you pass them the queue
    # upon construction). 
    for _ in range(number_of_workers):
        worker = Worker(queue)
        # you "daemonize" a thread to ensure that the threads will
        # close when the main program finishes
        worker.daemon = True        
        worker.start()

    # now it is time to add the jobs to the queue
    for _ in range(number_of_jobs):
        # a random duration between 2 and 5 seconds
        duration = random.randint(2,5) 
        queue.put(duration)

    # now wait for all workers to finish - JOIN THE QUEUE
    queue.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        nj = int(sys.argv[1])
        nw = int(sys.argv[2])
    else:
        nj = 10
        nw = 3

    # call main             
    main(nj, nw)
```

Sample output:

```
computer$ python example.py
25-Feb-2012 21:21:25.924856 UTC Thread-1: sleeping for 2 seconds
25-Feb-2012 21:21:25.925439 UTC Thread-2: sleeping for 3 seconds
25-Feb-2012 21:21:25.925523 UTC Thread-3: sleeping for 5 seconds
25-Feb-2012 21:21:27.925513 UTC Thread-1: finished sleeping
25-Feb-2012 21:21:27.925696 UTC Thread-1: sleeping for 5 seconds
25-Feb-2012 21:21:28.925561 UTC Thread-2: finished sleeping
25-Feb-2012 21:21:28.925742 UTC Thread-2: sleeping for 5 seconds
25-Feb-2012 21:21:30.925547 UTC Thread-3: finished sleeping
25-Feb-2012 21:21:30.925728 UTC Thread-3: sleeping for 5 seconds
25-Feb-2012 21:21:32.925781 UTC Thread-1: finished sleeping
25-Feb-2012 21:21:32.925963 UTC Thread-1: sleeping for 5 seconds
25-Feb-2012 21:21:33.925822 UTC Thread-2: finished sleeping
25-Feb-2012 21:21:33.926003 UTC Thread-2: sleeping for 2 seconds
25-Feb-2012 21:21:35.925833 UTC Thread-3: finished sleeping
25-Feb-2012 21:21:35.926013 UTC Thread-3: sleeping for 3 seconds
25-Feb-2012 21:21:35.926244 UTC Thread-2: finished sleeping
25-Feb-2012 21:21:35.926420 UTC Thread-2: sleeping for 5 seconds
25-Feb-2012 21:21:37.926035 UTC Thread-1: finished sleeping
25-Feb-2012 21:21:38.926158 UTC Thread-3: finished sleeping
25-Feb-2012 21:21:40.926697 UTC Thread-2: finished sleeping
computer$
```